# Creating a weird shadow effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm triying to create a shadow for a DIV, but it is no ordinary box shadow, is a shadow that looks like a Radial Shadow or someting.

[image]

I've tried with box-shadow but it doesn't work. What can i use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="shadow">Heading</div>
</div>


.shadow { background:#fff;padding:10px; border:solid 1px #ccc }
.box { position:relative; width:100%; margin-top:30px; z-index:0}
.box .shadow:after{
    bottom: -5px;
    content: " ";
    height: 8px;
    display:block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvcmFkaWFsR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iLTUwIiB5PSItNTAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDEiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQtdWNnZy1nZW5lcmF0ZWQpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side, #aaaaaa 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side, #aaaaaa 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side, #aaaaaa 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center top, 0, center top, 490, color-stop(0, #aaaaaa), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side, #aaaaaa 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-side, #aaaaaa 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}
```

Taken from: http://der-auftritt.de/testcase/gradientshadow.html

p.s. if you want the shadow at the top as well, use the :before selector with the same code

p.p.s. for some really cool gradients use this tool: [Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Wow, that is cool. It's so amazing what you can do these days. But in which browsers will it work? That would be info worth adding

Comment: @Pekka added the full cross browser code, the SVG hack is for IE

Comment: It works great! Thanks! But i can't make it work at the top. I think that there are things that need to be changed, like bottom: -5px, but i tried and it didn't worked. I will keep trying, thanks a lot!

Comment: @GalloPinto try top:-5px instead so that it goes 5px above the shadow container